# jQuery on hover show text for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, hover

I have social media buttons. Here is code:

```
<div id="icons">
        <a href="#twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>
        <a href="#facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
        <a href="#tumblr"><img src="images/tumblr.png"></a>
        <a href="#pinterest"><img src="images/pinterest.png"></a>
        <a href="#instagram"><img src="images/instagram.png"></a>
        <a href="#vk"><img src="images/vk.png"></a>
</div>
```

I want to show text on mouseover right to icon, depends where the pointer is. For example, if mouseover is on Facebook, show text next to Facebook icon. Here is code for text:

```
<div id="icons-text">
    <div class="hover-text">Like us on Twitter</div>
    <div class="hover-text">Like us on Facebook</div>
    <div class="hover-text">Follow us on Tumblr</div>
    <div class="hover-text">Follow us on Pinterest</div>
    <div class="hover-text">Follow us on Instagram</div>
    <div class="hover-text">Like us on VK</div>
</div>
```

I want to control that in jQuery. I have code:

```
$(function() {
     $('.hover-text').hide();
     $('#icons').hover( function() { $('.hover-text').toggle(); } );
});
```

CSS code:

```
#icons-text {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50px;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 999999;
}

.hover-text {
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 9pt;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
}
```

How can I in code select this elements and properly show text?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('#icons a').hover( function() { 
   $('.hover-text').eq($('#icons a').index($(this))).show();
} , function() { 
   $('.hover-text').eq($('#icons a').index($(this))).hide();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yevc7c28/)**

Comment: It's not working for me. I added CSS code in question.

Comment: @MarkoKos: i have updated the fiddle with css provided by you. works fine.

Comment: It's not working. Something elseis bothering the code. It's weird. When I put code in codepin, everything is working fine. And if I use normally to show all texts when the mouse is over, it's working, but this doesn't in Chrome.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/59xaw39a/ Here is working. But when I open in Chrome or Firefox or any other browser it's not working. I'm using normalize.css and bootstrap, I thought that might be problem, but it's not.

Comment: no its not. i already told you. you must be having position or z-index. it is not possible to help out unless you reproduce the problem for us.